# Setting dynamic global styles programmatically in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a Vue component that needs to control the background color of the entire page dynamically. It has an internal state, and that state has the side-effect of causing the background of the page to change.

Ordinarily *at the component level* this would be accomplished by using `v-bind` in CSS:

```
<style lang="scss">
.some-class {
  background-color: v-bind("some.variable");
}
</style>
```

This will work and the *component's* background will become the color defined in `some.variable`.

However, trying to use `v-bind` on `:root` (or anything outside of the component's scope) will fail. i.e.:

```
<style lang="scss">
html {
  background-color: v-bind("some.variable");
}
</style>
```

… will not set the CSS property correctly. This is because the variable is declared at the component level. i.e.:

CSS:

```
html {
  background-color: var(--something)
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <div style="--something">
</html>
```

What is therefore the "correct" or suggested practice? Do I manage it *as* a side-effect with watchers? Is there a flag to pass to `v-bind`?

Answer (score 3):

The best practice really depends on what is your goal.

If you want to set the background for **your app only** (maybe not the entry document), you can put your code inside the `App.vue` component. Now your variable will take the root scope of your app and apply to any class that is inside the `#app` element.

If you have to set the background for the `body` or `html` element, you have no choice but to use a watcher. The code is something like that:

```js
watch(someVariable, ()=>{
  document.body.style.setProperty('--background-color', someVariable.value);
})
```

Comment: The syntax must be `document.body.style.setProperty('--background-color', someVariable.value);`